# Redis in kubernetes - sidecar or client-server model?

Tags: caching, kubernetes, redis, persistent-storage, sidecar

What is the advantage and disadvantage of using **redis** as a sidecar in kubernetes?Is it possible to have persistence cache when redis container is added in each app pod? Will that affect the **availability** and **scalability** of cache?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm hard-pressed to think of any advantages to running Redis as a sidecar.  I would always run it as a separate deployment (or stateful set if persistence is enabled) with a separate service.

If Redis is in its own pod then:

- If your application has multiple replicas, they'll all share the same Redis
- When you redeploy your application, it doesn't also terminate and restart Redis
- If persistence is enabled for Redis, you don't need to configure your application pods with the persistent storage

Given Redis's overall capabilities (principally in-memory storage, limited data-type support), simply storing this cache data in singleton objects in your application would be more or less equivalent to running Redis as a sidecar (one copy of the cache data per pod, data is lost when the pod is deleted).

Comment: Thanks..However can we mention persistent storage that is shared by all redis sidecar containers?In that way will the latency in database calls decrease as there is no call to external redis pod?

Comment: If you measure it, and it's a significant problem to your application, you can revisit it.  The replication and data-lifetime issues are probably more important than saving a tiny fraction of a second per call.  Most things in Kubernetes cross the network and it's usually not a significant problem.

Comment: So I am thinking from the startup perspective,  I am storing very less cache entries but if I need to store million entries then how having a singleton objects for caching will scale? Or putting effort now for redis will payoff in long run when number of cache entries increase.
Or should I just stick to singletons for now then migrate to redis when needed.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with David Maze answer. In this op, REDIS is a long term cache which is the usual. All pods go to the same cache so they reuse it and it has a consistent output.

On the other hand, I am also evaluating a sidecar model for a redis cache, and in a nutshell, it all depends on your needs of consistency.

This sidecar redis means that each microservice pod would have its own redis. So when each microservice goes to the database, it then stores the object in its own redis. Whenever the same object is read, the microservice goes to redis, instead of database. This saves a lot of database readings but it penalizes the consistency. And it saves me $$ on cloud database readings.

In my case, the cache would expire in 1 minute or so, so the lack of consistency in-between is ok in my case.

In the case of scalability and availability I would even say it can increase it, since you can easily have many pods running. And even by putting a max memory on the redis pod, then you can easily restart it when reaching a limit (150mb?).

Comment: It's not that you can't do this.  You totally can.  However your cache lives with your pod.  It has the same cons as using in memory cache in your pods.  Making that container run in its own pod gives you server pods the ability to share that cache.